# How to filter the success message when using nc port scan

Tags: grep, nc

I used following command for port scanning of my machine

`nc -zv 192.168.1.1 1-100`

but I want to filter only succeeded message from  following output.Hence i used the following command

```
nc -zv 192.168.1.1 1-100|grep succeeded
```

But no use, still it shows full output

```
nc: connect to 192.168.1.1 port 1 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to 192.168.1.1 port 2 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to 192.168.1.1 port 3 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to 192.168.1.1 port 4 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to 192.168.1.1 port 5 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to 192.168.1.1 port 6 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to 192.168.1.1 port 7 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to 192.168.1.1 port 8 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to 192.168.1.1 port 9 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your command to this:

```
nc -zv 192.168.1.1 1-100 2>&1 | grep succeeded
```

`2>&1` causes `stderr` of a program to be written to the same file descriptor as `stdout`. `nc` writes to `stderr` by default, pipe will only get `stdout` hence grep will miss the data.

See section 3.5 here for more info [All about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

Comment: what is purpose of 2>&1 in this command

Comment: @P.G.Krish See updated answer.

Comment: But the terminal shows error messages as well as succeeded messages,  why we do another redirection for mixing error with output messages